# jqGrid - determine whether find or reset clicked in search window?

Tags: jquery, search, callback, jqgrid

We are using jqGrid [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching)..  how can you determine if a user has clicked Search, Reset, or has closed the search window?

There is an `onClose` event but it doesn't seem to have any parameters that indicate the action.

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on your question is depend on how you want to use the information. If you want that your callback function will be called you can use [beforeShowSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options) together with `onClose`:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true},// options
    {}, // settings for edit
    {}, // settings for add
    {}, // settings for delete
    {beforeShowSearch: function(form){
        $('.ui-search',form).click(function(){
            alert("in onSearch");
        });
        $('.ui-reset',form).click(function(){
            alert("in onReset");
        });
     },onClose: function(data){
            alert("in onClose");
     }
    } // search options
);
```

You should take in consideration, that your `onSearch` and `onReset` functions will be called **after** the main event handler, so the request to search or the request to reset is already sent. If you need to have the information **before** the search or reset the usage of `beforeRequest` request seems me very good. If you need to have search rules you can use `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData')` or just `$("#list")[0].p.postData`. The `postData` has `searchField`, `searchOper` and `searchString` (in case of [Single Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching)) or `filters` (in case of [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching)) set. In case of "Reset" the parameters are empty: "".

Comment: Thanks Oleg - good options.  Think I will likely go with the `beforeRequest` implementation - we'll see..

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we're using the `beforeRequest` grid event.

The `f` variable will be false if no searching is being performed, will be true otherwise:

```
beforeRequest: function() {
    var m = $("#status-header").is(":visible");
    var f = $("#list").getPostDataItem('_search');

    if ((m && !f) || (!m && f)) {
            $("#status-header").toggle('highlight',{},500);
    }       
},
```